# Issue Formatting Spreadsheet

Tags: excel

So I have a row:

```
         --------------------
         |  A   | B | C | D |
  -------|------|---|---|---|
  | row1 | test | 1 | 2 | 3 |
```

and from that row I would like to produce the following:

```
         ------------
         |  A   | B |
  -------|------|---|
  | row1 | test | 1 |
  -------|------|---|
  | row2 | test | 2 |
  -------|------|---|
  | row3 | test | 3 |
```

Are there any built in functions that might be able to handle this?

Comment: read about [`.Transpose`](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/transpose-excel-data-from-rows-to-columns-or-vice-versa/)

Comment: @mehow thank you for the tip my good sir! Also, do you know if there is a way to transpose on every third column?

Comment: sure see [`how the To and Step work`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687018/what-does-the-to-and-step-mean-in-vba/)

Comment: also consider using a [combination of transpose and array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481330/2-dimensional-array-vba-from-cell-contents-in-excel/)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use some form of unpivoting tool, like my unpivot add-in, available [here](http://tduhameau.wordpress.com/2012/09/24/the-unpivot-add-in/).