# Assignment to constant not allowed

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting this error in one of my macros, the code is

```
Dim rdel1 As Range
Dim rdel2 As Range
Set rdel1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(A1:B100)
For Each rdel2 In rdel1.Cells
    If rdel2.Value = "No item selected" Then
        rdel2.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
        rdel2.EntireRow.Delete
        rdel2.Address = rdel2.Offset(-1, 0)       "Error in this line"
    End If
Next rdel2
```

I want to change the address of redel2 by `offset(-1,0)`. I know it dosen't look the right way to write it but I am unable to get the right syntax to change it. Can someone help! Please!

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are actually doing. Can you explain what you are doing not what your code is doing? Do you want to iterate over a column and if a either column a or column b equals "No item selected" you want to delete the entire row? keep in mind when you are deleting rows/cells you need to [**iterate backwards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687018/what-does-the-to-and-step-mean-in-vba/19687126#19687126)**

Comment: @mehow Yeah you are right I should have started backwards. The problem that I was facing were there because I was going from top to the bottom. I did the changes now its working fine. So I no more need `rdel2.Address = rdel2.Offset(-1, 0)`

Comment: Using a auto-filter is much more efficient than  a range loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you execute

```
rdel2.EntireRow.Delete
```

`rdel2` will be `Nothing' so any attempt to manipulate it will fail.

If it were *not* `Nothing`, and referenceing a cell in a row > 1, then

```
Set rdel2 = rdel2.Offset(-1, 0)
```

would work.

It's not clear exactly what you want to achieve, but this may get you started

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim rdel1 As Range
    Dim rdel2 As Range

    Set rdel1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A100")
    Dim rw As Long
    For rw = rdel1.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set rdel2 = rdel1.Cells(rw, 1)
        If rdel2.Value = "No item selected" Then
            rdel2.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`rdel2` is a range and `.Offset(-1,0)` returns a range, just do `rdel2 = rdel2.Offset(-1, 0)` if you want to change `rdel2`.

Although, in your case, the `For Each` loop will update `rdel2` so this line will be useless (unless you are not showing all your code and there is actually more between the problematic line and the `Next rdel2` statement)