# Macro - delete rows based on date

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA and macros in Excel. I have a very large excel spreadsheet in which column A holds dates. I am trying to delete the rows which have a value smaller than a certain date and this is what I have come up with till now..

```
Sub DELETEDATE()
Dim x As Long
For x = 1 To Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Debug.Print Cells(x, "A").Value
If CDate(Cells(x, "A")) < CDate("01/01/2013") Then
Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next x
Next i
End Sub
```

I am receiving a Next without For error... can somebody help please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This lends itself well to using the `.AutoFilter` property of a `Range`. The script below contains a comment for each step taken:

```
Option Explicit
Sub DeleteDateWithAutoFilter()

Dim MySheet As Worksheet, MyRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long

'turn off alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'set references up-front
Set MySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'identify the last row in column A and the last col in row 1
'then assign a range to contain the full data "block"
With MySheet
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Range("A" & .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set MyRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
End With

'apply autofilter to the range showing only dates
'older than january 1st, 2013, then deleting
'all the visible rows except the header
With MyRange
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<1/1/2013"
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count).Rows.Delete
End With

'turn off autofilter safely
With MySheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    If .FilterMode = True Then
        .ShowAllData
    End If
End With

'turn alerts back on
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Running this code on a simple example (on "Sheet1" in this picture) that looks like this:

[image: start]

Will delete all rows with a date older than 1/1/2013, giving you this result:

[image: end]

Comment: thanks! i made some changes to the code and it worked fine! thanks!

Comment: Great -- glad to hear that it worked out. If an answer suits you, please accept it at your convenience. Here's a super-quick explanation in the form of a screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question

> I am receiving a Next without For error

The problem is you are trying to loop on `i` but you haven't opened a `For i` loop.  When you indent the code below any code that invokes a `Loop` or condition (i.e. `If`) it becomes obvious

```
Sub DELETEDATE()
Dim x As Long
    For x = 1 To Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        Debug.Print Cells(x, "A").Value
        If CDate(Cells(x, "A")) < CDate("01/01/2013") Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete 'i has no value so Cells(0, "A") is ??
        End If
    Next x
    Next i 'where is the For i = ... in this code?
End Sub
```

When writing code I try to:

- Enter the end command immediately if it's needed. So type `If...Then`, hit `[ENTER]`, type `End If`,  hit `[HOME]`, hit `[ENTER]`, hit `[UP ARROW]` then `[TAB]` to the right place to write the conditional code so that anyone will be able to read and understand it easily.
- Always use `Option Explicit` at the top of every module to force variable declarations.

**a tip about deleting rows based on a condition**
If you start at the top and work down, every time you delete a row your counter will effectively move to the cell two rows below the row you deleted because the row immediately below the deleted row moves up (i.e. it is not tested at all).

The most efficient way is to loop up from the bottom or your rows:

```
Sub DELETEDATE()
Dim x As Long
    For x = [a1].SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row To 1 Step -1
        Debug.Print Cells(x, "A").Value
        If CDate(Cells(x, "A")) < CDate("01/01/2013") Then
            Cells(x, "A").EntireRow.Delete 'changed i to x
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

This way, the next row you want to test has been preserved - you've only moved the row below up by 1 and you've tested that row earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this

```
Sub DELETEDATE()
Dim x As Long
last = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
For x = 1 To last
    Debug.Print Cells(x, "A").Value
    check:
    If x <= last Then
        If Trim(CDate(Cells(x, "A"))) <= Trim(CDate("7/29/2013")) Then
            last = last - 1
            Cells(x, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            GoTo check
        End If
    End If
Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You have an additional `Next i` for some reason in your code as highlighted by the debugger. Try the below:

```
Sub DELETEDATE()
Dim x As Long
For x = 1 To Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Debug.Print Cells(x, "A").Value
If CDate(Cells(x, "A")) < CDate("01/01/2013") Then
Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: how come i is still remaining empty?

Comment: because index is shifting when deleting rows. You need to [iterate backwards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687018/what-does-the-to-and-step-mean-in-vba/19687126#19687126)

Comment: how is the date format usually written in vba? cause i m having a type mismatch