# VBA Macro to Autofilter One Date and Special Cells Delete

Tags: excel, vba, office365, autofilter, excel-365

I am modifying this code, [Macro - delete rows based on date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033022/macro-delete-rows-based-on-date).

```
Sub DeleteDateWithAutoFilter()

Dim MySheet As Worksheet, MyRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long

'turn off alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'set references up-front
Set MySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")

'identify the last row in column A and the last col in row 1
'then assign a range to contain the full data "block"
With MySheet
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Range("A" & .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set MyRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
End With
    
'apply autofilter to the range showing only dates
'older than january 1st, 2013, then deleting
'all the visible rows except the header
With MyRange
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<8/5/2021"
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count).Rows.Delete
End With

'turn off autofilter safely
With MySheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    If .FilterMode = True Then
        .ShowAllData
    End If
End With

'turn alerts back on
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

So far I have added an input box where the user can define the date they are looking for. This is working great.

```
Sub EditedCode()

Dim MySheet As Worksheet, MyRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
Dim myValue As String

'turn off alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'set references up-front
Set MySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet13")

myValue = InputBox("Enter Date in XX/XX/XXXX Format", "Date Selection", " ")
Range("Y1") = myValue
```

From here I want to autofilter just the input date to then use .SpecialCells to delete everything but the selected date. I've tried using criteria1/Operator/Criteria2 but I cannot get this to work. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Current Full Code:

```
Sub EditedCode()

Dim MySheet As Worksheet, MyRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
Dim myValue As String

'turn off alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'set references up-front
Set MySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet13")

myValue = InputBox("Enter Date in XX/XX/XXXX Format", "Date Selection", " ")
Range("Y1") = myValue

'identify the last row in column A and the last col in row 1
'then assign a range to contain the full data "block"
With MySheet
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Range("A" & .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set MyRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
End With

'apply autofilter to the range showing only dates using above input
'older than inputed date, then deleting
'all the visible rows except the header
With MyRange
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=& myValue"
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count).Rows.Delete
End With

'turn off autofilter safely
With MySheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    If .FilterMode = True Then
        .ShowAllData
    End If
End With

'turn alerts back on
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

I have also tried changing the type of myValue and using different funtions on autofilter (<,>,=). Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

[Example of ws](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7sU6.png)

Comment: For deleting rows, instead of filtering on the date, I think you will get much better performance if you SORT by date. Then you have only 2 blocs of rows to delete. Deleting row by row is very expensive in terms of performance.